# string comparison

Tags: c#

Are there any open source algorithms in c# that solve the problem of creating a difference between two text files?

It would be super cool if it had some way of highlighting what exact areas where changed in the text document also.

Comment: Being a Beyond Compare owner, I've never felt the need for such an algorithm. :) http://www.scootersoftware.com/

Answer (score 3):

Give a look to the following libraries:

- [A Generic, Reusable Diff Algorithm](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/diffengine.aspx)
- [An O(ND) Difference Algorithm for C#](http://www.mathertel.de/Diff/)
- [Diff/Merge/Patch Library for C#/.NET](http://razor.occams.info/code/diff/)
- [Diff.NET](http://www.menees.com/DiffDotNet.htm)